# Cocoa: is it possible to put a raw image in a view just with a pointer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers

I would like to ask if it is possible with Cocoa classes to have a direct pointer to  the internal graphical image of a view and put a raw graphical image into that (private?) memory area, 
or viceversa tell that view the pointer to a raw image in another memory area. 
I ask if Cocoa allows this low-level operations. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. You need to wrap that internal representation with a `CGImage` (via [CGImageCreate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreate)), and depending on context, you would then need to wrap the `CGImage` with an `UIImage`.

Comment: Note: the OP asks about Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch.

Comment: @Caleb: Argh, thanks for noticing. Though AFAIK it's still correct, except that `UIImage` should be `NSImage` instead.

Comment: I read on Apple docs that the OS allows also low level access to the system, so I believe there is a way to have a direct pointer connection as above mentioned, that is, going beyond Cocoa (Cocoa or Cocoa Touch) but still managing those views

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that an "internal graphical image of a view" even exists? Some views may, others may not, but if such a thing exists it is by definition "internal" and therefore not something you should mess with. However, you do have access to a view's layer, and that gives you a lot of control.

What are you trying to do? If you just want to get a copy of the contents of a view as an image, that's easy, and if you want to draw an image in a view that's easy too. Once you have an image, you can do just about anything you want to change it.